# Debug Firefox extension on android mobile via usb

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-developer-tools

I'm able to debug firefox on my android device via usb (using the adb debug tool in webIDE), but am having trouble seeing any output/errors from an extension I'm running on the mobile device.

Normally (on desktop) I would open a separate extension debugging console via about:debugging.  Since that's not an option on mobile,  I tried enabling js errors with the javascript.options.showInConsole  property and still haven't had any luck.

Any ideas on how to get the typical output from an extension (background.js etc.)  to show up in the webIDE debug console when connected to the device over usb?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking, you can access the background.js context by:

Opening webIDE and making usb connection to the phone

Clicking the "main process" tab on the left, and opening the JS console there.  All extension console.log() calls will show up there.